# Differing options for UIPageViewController.transitionStyle in Xcode GUI vs Programmatic Enum

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, xcode10

I'm using a storyboard to build an app where one page requires a UIPageViewController within a ContainerView. Everything works fine, but I'd like to use the scroll transition style rather than the default "page turn" animation.

Looking at the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller/transitionstyle) I get two options - page curl and scroll, but when I open what I assumed would be the corresponding menu in XCode, I get the options below.

[image: Transitional Style Xcode Options]

Note - regardless of which option I select in this menu, printing self.transitionStyle.rawValue on my subclass of UIPageViewController gives me "0", which corresponds to the pageCurl case of the TransitionStyle enum (see below).

[image]

Am I missing something? Does that drop-down refer to some other transitional style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look at `UIViewController`'s modal transition style not `UIPageViewController`'s one. If you create `UIPageViewController` in Storyboard you'll see another transition style in "Page View Controller" block in Interface Builder.

About `UIViewController`'s transition style you can read [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodaltransitionstyle).

[image: Page View Controller]

Comment: Ah. Thank you very much Peter.
Appears that XCode hasn't recognised my View as a PageViewController and therefore those options weren't available. This is because I merely changed the class of the UIViewController automatically created by the addition of a ContainerView, rather than dragging in a fresh Page View Controller - I guess the storyboard view doesn't update the options accordingly.